# Use options to filter data inside of a table with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactstrap

So basically I'm working with a large dataset that gives you a list of videos (about 100-200) for each day in this year (2018, so the data is from January 1st, 2018 to February 18th, 2018). What I want to do is use a table to show all of the videos in ONE day. I'm using the `<option>` tag for the list of all the dates. I'm currently stuck because I'm trying to make it where you click on a certain date, a table will generate and show the list of videos from that day with the video name and the channel that posted the video. Here is a copy of my code:

The code below is to generate each row in the table:

```
// Simple TableRow component for showing a <tr>

class TableRow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          { this.props.date }
        </td>
        <td>
          { this.props.title }
        </td>
        <td>
          { this.props.channel }
        </td>
        <td>
          { this.props.view }
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src={ this.props.photo }></img>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

The code below is to generate the whole table and calls on the `TableRow`

```
// Class for a table

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  // Should return a TableRow component for each element in this.props.data
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Video Name</th>
              <th>Channel</th>
              <th>Views</th>
              <th>Photo</th>
            </tr>
            { this.props.songs.map(function(d, i) {
              return <TableRow key={ 'song-' + i } date={ d.trending_date } title={ d.title } channel={ d.channel_title } view={d.views} photo={ d.thumbnail_link } />
          }) }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Finally, this is where I'm doing the bulk of the work. This function is generating the options and creating the table based on the specific date. `this.props.data` is the dataset passed into the `Options` class from a different class

```
class Options extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '18.01.01',
      data: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Gets the trending dates but ignores duplicates
    let dateData = d3.nest()
      .key((d) => { return d.trending_date })
      .entries(this.props.data);

    return (
      <div>
          Choose a Date:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            { dateData.map((d) => {
              return <option value={d.key}>{d.key}</option>
            }) }
          </select>

          <Table songs={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use `this.state.value` to get the VALUE in the object, `dateData`, since `dateData` contains all of the videos for each date. However, I can't seem to find a way to set `this.state.data` to the correct dataset to pass into the `Table` class... Does anybody have any ideas how I can approach this problem?

Example of how the dataset looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rofrw.png

Comment: Can you show us how data looks? Is it an array of song objects with attributes title, date, channel and view?

Comment: Updated my post!

Comment: it should be fairly easy to filter that kind of data! I'll write an answer

Comment: I guess I'm struggling with trying to filter it using the <options> and putting it in a table... T-T Any help would be great!!

Comment: I've been stumped for the past hour or so because this.state.data is either undefined or empty so my table ends up blank since the data is empty!

Comment: where are you using the options filter on your code? is it inside the Table component?

Comment: It's inside my Options component. And then my Options component is calling the Table component to create the table

Comment: Also I wasn't sure how else to get rid of the duplicates in my original dataset (like my original dataset had a date for each video, which isn't what I want. I just want one date that corresponds to all 200 videos) so I used d3, which is the dateData variable. The keys in that are all of the dates, while the values are the videos